# Filter on Visualforce Table

Tags: visualforce, filters, table

I would like to filter the column "Status" of my table by selecting a value in a pick list which is integrated in the column header:

**Markup**

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="maintable">
    <thead class="rich-table-thead">
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th class="headerRow">Dev Request Name</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Status &nbsp;&nbsp;                               
                <apex:selectList id="searchStatus" value="{!selectedStatus}" size="1" onchange="getlistDevRequests">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Status}" />
                </apex:selectList></th>
            <th class="headerRow">Start Date</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Due Date QA</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Estimated Hours</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Assignee</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Overview</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <apex:repeat value="{!lstDevRequests}"  var="item">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="dataRow">
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Name}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50"><span class="status" >{!item.Status__c}</span></td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50"><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!item.Start_Date__c}" /> </apex:outputText></td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50"><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!item.Due_Date_QA__c}" /> </apex:outputText></td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Estimated_Hours__c}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Assignee__r.Name}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Overview__c}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class tableDevRequests {

    List<Dev_Request__c> lstDevRequests;
    public String selectedStatus{get;set;}


    public tableDevRequests() {

    }


    public List<SelectOption> getStatus() {
        List<SelectOption> statOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
        statOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--All Status--'));
        for( Dev_Request__c dev : [select Id,Status__c from Dev_Request__c ] ) {
            statOptions.add( new SelectOption(dev.Id,dev.Status__c)); /*SelectOption list takes two parameters one is value and other one is label .In this case account name as a label and Id is the value .*/
        }
        return statOptions;
    }



    public List<Dev_Request__c> getlstDevRequests() {
        if(lstDevRequests == null)
            lstDevRequests = [Select Id, Name, Assignee__c, Assignee__r.Name, Start_Date__c, Due_Date_QA__c, Estimated_Hours__c, Estimated_Completion_Date__c, Status__c, Overview__c, Parent_Dev_Request__c, (SELECT Id, WhatId, ActivityDAte, Owner.Name, Description, Status, Subject from Tasks) from Dev_Request__c];
        return lstDevRequests;
    }
}
```

How would I modify my code?

Comment: your code is incomplete, please complete your code and post specific issue over SFSE and here nothing is 'Urgent'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<apex:actionSupport/>` wrapped into `<apex:selectList/>` and pass the selected value to the controller method.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:selectList id="searchStatus" value="{!selectedStatus}" size="1">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Status}" id="field"/>
      <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="tableData" action="{!getlstDevRequests}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Create an `<apex:outputPanel/>` where data table will be displayed and will be reRendered from actionSupport.

```
<apex:outputPanel id= "tableData">
    <apex:repeat value="{!lstDevRequests}"  var="item">
       <!-- rows to display-->
   </apex:repeat>
<apex:outputPanel/>
```

**Apex Class**

In the `getlstDevRequests` you will receive the `selectedStatus` value and perform the query based on that.

```
public PageReference  getlstDevRequests() 
{
    if(selectedStatus =='') 
    {       
        lstDevRequests = [Select Id, Name, Assignee__c, Assignee__r.Name, Start_Date__c, 
        Due_Date_QA__c, Estimated_Hours__c, Estimated_Completion_Date__c, Status__c, 
        Overview__c, Parent_Dev_Request__c, 
        (SELECT Id, WhatId, ActivityDAte, Owner.Name, Description, Status, Subject from Tasks) 
        from Dev_Request__c];
    }
    else
    {       
        lstDevRequests = [Select Id, Name, Assignee__c, Assignee__r.Name, Start_Date__c, 
        Due_Date_QA__c, Estimated_Hours__c, Estimated_Completion_Date__c, Status__c, 
        Overview__c, Parent_Dev_Request__c, 
        (SELECT Id, WhatId, ActivityDAte, Owner.Name, Description, Status, Subject from Tasks) 
        from Dev_Request__c
        WHERE Status__c =:fieldValue];
    }        
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Note: I haven't compiled the code, I have tried to give you logic to render data based on selection

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your code, I did substitute fieldValue with selectedStatus.  However, now I get this error: Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: visualforce.el.VisualforceArrayList

Comment: Just change return type to pagereference, and return null from the method

Comment: Now my list on the page displays nothing (

Comment: Dear Santana, thank you very much so far for your appreciated help. However, when I look into it, it seems the table body does not get rendered properly. It just shows me the table header. Thus, when I select a status, it does not do anything. I try to play around a bit, but if you have any further idea, that would be great. Maybe it helps if I put my new code here, as it has changed a bit since last time, and it is a bit more complex than just the code above?

Comment: you can ask separate ques and close this question

Answer (score 1):

If temporarily hiding the rows is fine with you then I will try like;

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="maintable">
    <thead class="rich-table-thead">
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th class="headerRow">Dev Request Name</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Status                                  
                <apex:selectList id="searchStatus" value="{!selectedStatus}" size="1" onchange="getlistDevRequests">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Status}" />
                </apex:selectList></th>
            <th class="headerRow">Start Date</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Due Date QA</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Estimated Hours</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Assignee</th>
            <th class="headerRow">Overview</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <apex:repeat value="{!lstDevRequests}"  var="item">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="dataRow">
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Name}</td>
                <td class="statusCol" bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Status__c}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50"><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!item.Start_Date__c}" /> </apex:outputText></td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50"><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!item.Due_Date_QA__c}" /> </apex:outputText></td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Estimated_Hours__c}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Assignee__r.Name}</td>
                <td bgcolor="#faffff" height="50">{!item.Overview__c}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function getlistDevRequests()
 {
    var selectedStatus = $('[id$="searchStatus"]').value;
    if(selectedStatus != -1)
        $('.statusCol').each(function(){
            if($(this).value() !=  selectedStatus)
                $(this).closest(".dataRow").attr('style','display:none;');
        })
    else
        $('.dataRow').attr('style','display:');
 }
</script>
```

I have **added jQuery script, a javascript method and removed span from status__c column**.

And please add

```
statOptions.add( new SelectOption('-1','--All Status--'));
```

in apex class.

Note: I have not checked it in my org for compilation errors. Please verify in your org.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, that does not function. What could be wrong here? Also, I already have JavaScript included in my code. How would I avoid conflicts?

function switchMenu(obj,obj1,obj2) 
        {
            var el = document.getElementById(obj);                                       
            if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
            } ...